# ヘッダーやフッターを付けて印刷することは可能でしょうか。

Tags: macos, lpr

macのターミナル(bash)で印刷をしました。lprコマンドで画像ファイル（png)を印刷したのですが、例えば、ファイル名がhana.pngの場合、Excel等で印刷する時と同じように、印刷画像のヘッダーにファイル名のhana.png、続けて、プリントアウトの日時を追加することは可能でしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

linuxのlprコマンドには、タイトルを指定する -T オプションがあります。

```
lpr -T "hana.png 2018/02/08 12:34"
```

というように -T　に続けてヘッダに印刷したい文字列を指定します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。lpr -T "hana.png 2018/02/08 12:34" hana.png　で印刷はできるのですが、やはりヘッダーは印刷されません。何故でしょうか？　-Tオプションが効いてない感じですね。